# jScrollPane doesn't display when ajax reloads content of a block

Tags: javascript

There is another problem related to the ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736293/jquery-script-not-working-with-ajax/7736669#7736669)) query. When i load/reload the whole page, it displays jquery scroll pane on my content list but if i click on a link that call `myContentList();` javascript and update my content list then jquery scroll pane doesn't display. Basically it doestn't load/reload the whole page, only refreshes the contents of `<div id="contentListDiv" class="list jp-container"></div>`.

Thanks!